# Take Text from an EntryBox and then write it to a txt file

Tags: python, tkinter

All,
I have attempted this a few different ways and am still struggling here.

I want to have someone write in this Entry Box and then once submit is hit, it should write the text to the .txt file. I'm obviously not very good.

```
import datetime
from tkinter import *

def save():
    with open("text.txt", "a") as f:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        test = TxtComplaint.get()
        test = str(test)
        f.write(test)
        f.write(now)

window = Tk()
window.title("Documentation Window")
lbl = Label(window, text = "Enter In The Employee's Information")
TxtComplaint = Text(window, height = '10', width = '30')
benter = Button(window, text="Submit", command = save())
TxtComplaint.pack()

ee = Entry(window)
eelbl = Label(window, text = "Whats the name of the employee?")
eename = str(lbl)
lbl.pack()
benter.pack()
ee.pack()
eelbl.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the command, not the result of the command, to the Button. IOW leave off the (). It should be like this: `benter = Button(window, text="Submit", command = save)`. Also you need to convert now to a string before writing, like this: `f.write(str(now))`